# Teamcity, MSBUILD ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo task fails

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, teamcity

It seems like everything has broken overnight at the same time... sigh.

In a desperate attempt to fix other random problems I need to make a build of our large project only to find that our teamcity build agents can no longer do their job. The error message is below:

```
[CallTarget] Version (1s)
[Version] MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo (1s)

[MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo] I:\BuildAgent-DEVTC1\work\e7d35660eba50bd6\build.proj(150, 3): error MSB4018: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(String input)
   at MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Version.ParseVersion(String version) in     D:\Projects\MSBuildExtensionPack\Releases\4.0.3.0\Main\Framework\Framework\AssemblyInfo\Version.cs:line 51
   at MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo.Execute() in D:\Projects\MSBuildExtensionPack\Releases\4.0.3.0\Main\Framework\Framework\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.cs:line 1011
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

The proj definition for the Version target is the following where @VersionDefinition is an "inlcude" for all AssemblyInfo.cs files:

```
<Target Name="Version">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo
            AssemblyInfoFiles="@(VersionDefinition)"
            AssemblyVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)"
            AssemblyCopyright="Copywrite info here"
            AssemblyCompany="Company info here"
            AssemblyFileVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)"/>
</Target>
```

I can see that teamcity is correctly passing in BUILD_NUMBER with a valid value too.

Any ideas?

I'm open to suggestions that don't rely on the extension pack to set AssemblyInfo.cs numbers. I have looked into the TeamCity Assembly Info Patcher but I wasn't sure what "standard locations" was referring to in its description.

On a side note, have there been any updates recently to windows or .NET that could have broken everything...everywhere? I have recently had numerous third party libraries start to fail, almost simultaneously.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
The logs for recent successful build do not even show the Version target being called... which is odd given that that's the only place the correct build number is set and the build created files with the correct number applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I installed a newer version of the ExtensionPack (4.0.13.0) on to the build clients and got a slightly clearer error message that told me which file was at fault.

Examining the AssemblyInfo.cs file mentioned the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion values were missing. Adding these solved the issue.

The interesting part here is that the suspect project has not been touched for years so the values had never have been set. A quick scan through our git logs confirms this. Ultimately I'm not sure what triggered this to become a problem but it is no longer.